# Quotient of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Is it true that $$\mathbb{Z/4Z\subseteq Z/2Z}$$
Why precisely? Or the reverse $$\mathbb{Z/2Z \subseteq Z/4Z}$$ holds? I'm a beginner. How do I justify the true inclusion? 
How do I visualize $$\mathbb{Z/2Z \subseteq Z/4Z}$$
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried writing down the elements of each group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be true because $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ has $4$ elements but $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has only $2$ elements.

$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not true because a class mod $2$ is not a class mod $4$.

Nevertheless, the classes $0 + 4\mathbb{Z}$ and $2 + 4\mathbb{Z}$ behave additively like the classes $0 + 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $1 + 2\mathbb{Z}$. In that sense, we may say that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, but it is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Won't deny that your answer is correct, but since you took the time to answer a question you might also want to assure that a beginner can follow your steps. Throwing a bunch of notation might be quick, short and mistake free, but might not help the beginner to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The objects $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ are **sets** but also they're **groups**.

Thinking about them as sets we have $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} = \{0,1,2,3\}$ and as **sets** $\{0,1\}\subseteq \{0,1,2,3\}$.

This inclusion is not true as **groups**! It is because $1+1=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ but $1+1=2$ is $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

It is still possible to think about $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ by identifying $1$ with $2$. In other words the subset $\{0,2\}$ under $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ addition is "isomorphic" to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (basically because $2+2=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: I upvoted your response for clarifying the difference between the subset and subgroup relationship. However, the subset relationship isn't exactly true because the $0$ in $\mathbb Z$ mod 2 is the set of even integers and the $0$ in $\mathbb Z$ mod 4 is the set of integers divisible by $4$.